# How to change default time to live table value in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a requirement to change default time to live value for tables in cassandra from 5 to 10 days .If I alter table and set the new ttl value what will happened to existing data. Please suggest best option to do it for production data.

Answer (score 0):

TTL is the value which decides that how much time data will live into the table before tombstones. A good explanation by Datastax here.

TTL (Time To Live) in seconds, where zero is disabled. The maximum configurable value is 630720000 (20 years). If the value is greater than zero, TTL is enabled for the entire table and an expiration timestamp is added to each column. A new TTL timestamp is calculated each time the data is updated and the row is removed after all the data expires.
Default value: 0 (disabled). You can refer more details for table all table properties in Cassandra.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTable.html#tabProp__cqlTableDefaultTTL

For changing default_time_to_live you need to alert the table properties as given in above link.

Answer (score 0):

Any change to the default TTL value of the table would be applied to new updates (new writes or updates) coming into the table. TTL value of the existing columns would remain as it was calculated at the time of that column value update.

It's not clear from your question what your requirement is of existing data. If you want to update the TTL value for existing column values too, AFAIK there is no easy way to do that.